# Change image Attr alt, to <li>sample title</>

Tags: javascript, jquery, playlist, alt

**I have a JS  _buildPlaylist file, and Isee this for example:**

```
//create thumb
                thumb=$(new Image()).addClass('thumb_img').appendTo(div).attr('alt', _item.title?_item.title:'').css({
                   cursor:'pointer',
                   opacity:0
                }).load(function() {
                    $(this).stop().animate({ 'opacity':1}, {duration: 500, easing: 'easeOutSine'});//fade in thumb
                }).error(function(e) {

                }).attr('src', _item.thumbnail);
```

The line for crear image thumb with "alt title name"

**This is the result:**

```
 <img class="thumb_img" alt="Sample title builded here" style="cursor: pointer; opacity: 1;" src="http://mywebsite.com/image.jpg">
```

---

As you can see, this creates an image with an alt text attribute

Now, I want to change to build a < LI > List names

- Sample title builded here  (*this is the ALT title name*)

**So, how can I change the image thumb to a text, or show alt title only?**

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use `img` tag if you dont want to display image.
Just give it as a `label` or a `link`. That will do.

Answer (score -1):

Rather than building off a `new Image()`, build off of an `<a>` wrapped in a `<li>`:

```
var thumb = $("<a>", { 
    'class': 'thumb_item', 
    'text' : (_item.title ? _item.title : "No title"),
    'href' : _item.thumbnail
}).wrap("<li>").parent().appendTo(div);​
```

Of course we would do away with the `.load` and `.error` handlers, since these events don't take place on list items.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tudwA/